# Finding load current in a circuit with voltage dependent voltage source

Tags: circuit-analysis, current, resistors, current-source, voltage-source

<sub>**This question has been rolled back to the version that doesn't invalidate  the answers (edit by Andy aka)**</sub>

---

I'm currently studying for my Circuit Analysis class, the teacher shared some questions and their answers with us, but not the steps of reaching the answers. I solved almost all of them, but whatever I try doesn't work for this question. Can you guide me, how can I reach the solution?

Teacher says the answer is \$I_L= 1,68 mA.\$

**Edit:** I tried Norton's theorem first since it asks for the load current, but I just can't get rid of the dependent source, I tried Thevenin and superposition as well but I can't seem to make it work. It's probably my bad, I'm doing something I shouldn't with the equations.

**With Norton:** I tried mesh analysis after shorting RL, and used supernode because there is IS in the middle of the meshes, but it doesn't work, I can't get rid of 2Va, using \$2V_a = 36i_1\$ doesn't work, since that leads me to \$i_2 = 3,648\$ which supposed to be my IL, but it's wrong, since the real answer is supposed to be 1,68 mA.

What I did was set clockwise i1 and i2. From supernode I got:

\$3,5 - 18i_1 - 7i_1 +2V_A = 0\\V_a = 18i_1\\3,5 -11i_1 = 0\\i_1=0,318\$

Then, IL is i2, so:
\$i_2 = i_1+3,3 = 3,648mA\$ which is wrong.

[image: question]

Comment: so, what *were* your steps, so we can help you get them right?

Comment: @MarcusMüller sorry, I edited the question.

Comment: Thanks! I'd be careful with superposition here, indeed, but the other two approaches should take you somewhere; could you add to the question which simplifications you did before trying to apply Thevenin's or Norton's equivalent?

Comment: Shouldn't you need the value of RL?

Comment: @Andy V_s&(R_1 series R_2)-> CC source in par with I_s, the dependent source sets the voltage from that, and current is fix.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I added my steps looking at my papers. Sorry again for not giving enough information.

Comment: I cannot see how this can be solved without knowing RL (60.9 kohm)

Comment: @Andyaka teacher is persistent about not giving RL, so I'm trying to find a way to get rid of RL.

Comment: @BerkayGünaydın well good luck, but, as far as I can tell, unless you have made a diagrammatical error in your schematic, you need the value of RL (60.905 kohms as I estimate).

Comment: @Andyaka I got the question directly from what he sent to the class chat. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Berkay Gunaydin are you studying EE and if yes where?

Comment: @TheForceAwakens No, I'm studying computer engineering.

Comment: Is this a 1st /2nd semester subject?(Electronics I and Electronics II)?

Comment: @TheForceAwakens No I got Electronics as a single semester class last year.This is a follow up, Circuit Analysis class. This is a single semester class as well.

Comment: It seems to me that your task is to find the RL that will give you the maximum power transferred to the load resistance (RL).

Comment: You get a singularity at RL=R1-R2

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 clarify .

Comment: @TheForceAwakens  nevermind , got my Va polarity reversed.  RL solution is indeed for max Pd for RL=61.00k

Comment: With the (rolled back) modification , saying that I(RL)=Ishort/2 implies the load satisfies the maximum power transfer, as [G36 mentions](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/546865/finding-load-current-in-a-circuit-with-voltage-dependent-voltage-source#comment1421998_546865). Maybe this was part of the question and you forgot to add it. Becasuse that would have changed everything.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen the question didn't mention about maximum power transfer but I should've guessed it was included, he really likes asking about max power without telling it's about that. I see now, thanks a lot good sir.

Comment: @BerkayGünaydın See the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I cannot see how this can be solved without knowing RL (60.9 kohm)

> *@Andyaka teacher is persistent about not giving RL, so I'm trying to
> find a way to get rid of RL*

Please note that my "answer" is **IS NOT** a homework solution so please don't think it is.

My "answer" simply attempts to show that resistor RL **needs to be known** in order to determine the current through it. In other words, the question set by the teacher is **flawed** or the interpretation given by the OP is **incorrect**.

Redraw the picture with what you know about the problem and the apparent "solution": -

- The resistor values R1 and R2
- The 3.3 mA current source
- The 3.5 volts voltage source
- The "correct" current through RL of 1.68 mA

Then, because you know the current must split and add up to 3.3 mA, the current through resistors R1 and R2 must be 1.62 mA: -

[image]

This then means that the voltage at the top of the current source has to be: -

3.5 volts + (18 kΩ + 7 kΩ)•1.62 mA = 44.000 volts: -

[image]

You also know the voltage across R1 (aka VA) = 1.62 mA • 18000 = 29.16 volts

And, 2•VA = 58.32 volts hence, the voltage across resistor RL must be 44 volts + 58.32 volts = 102.32 volts: -

[image]

This cannot mean anything else other than that the resistor RL must have a value of: -

102.32 volts ÷ 1.68 mA = 60904.76 Ω.

And, if that doesn't convince you, here's the result of a simulation: -

[image]

Should I change RL to (say 50 kΩ) we get a different current distribution and the wrong answer: -

[image]

---

A note about maximum power transfer (following comments). If the "real" question sought to find the current in RL when the maximum power was transferred to RL then RL would equal 61 kΩ. This is because the presence of the VCVS (with a gain of 2) would make an equivalent impedance of twice R1. Given that finding the Thevenin equivalent impedance means we can ignore the current source, the total Thevenin impedance is R1 + R2 +2•R1 = 61 kΩ. And when RL equals that value, we have maximum power transfer and I(RL) would be 1.67869 mA.

Comment: Homework questions that show effort like this one are fine

Comment: @Andyaka you might want to check the question now, since I found a solution and changed the question

Comment: @BerkayGünaydın No, this isn’t good. You asked a question and I completely answered it and you accepted the answer. Now you are changing that question significantly and that completely makes my answer look stupid. What you should do is, roll back your question modification and, if you have a new question based on fresh information, formally ask a brand new question. I’m trusting that you see the error of your ways in what you have done and do as I ask. Let me know when you have restored this question and have asked a new question and I shall be pleased to take a look.

Comment: @BerkayGünaydın OK, you are not responding to this so I'm taking the liberty of rolling back your question to the previous version so that it doesn't invalidate the given answers.

Comment: @Andyaka sorry about not responding, your answer never looked stupid and I appreciate it. The reason I mentioned you because I found what was wrong and since you were interested, thought you might wanna know. I still gonna accept your answer because it was helpful, sorry about the misunderstanding.

Comment: @BerkayGünaydın I thought there might still have been a doubt in your mind about the solution. Your teacher appeared to be guiding you down the maximum power transfer route and, that was discussed in comments above this and I added that to my answer yesterday in case that was the possible reason for the original question.

Answer (score 4):

Well, we are trying to analyze the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7gSld.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws), we can write the following set of equations:

$$\text{I}_2=\text{I}_\text{k}+\text{I}_1\tag1$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_3}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

And we also know that \$\text{V}_3-\text{V}_2=\text{n}\cdot\left(\text{V}_1-\text{V}_\text{i}\right)\$.

Substitute \$(2)\$ into \$(1)\$, in order to get:

$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_3}=\text{I}_\text{k}+\frac{\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\frac{\text{V}_3}{\text{R}_3}=\text{I}_\text{k}+\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{V}_3-\text{V}_2=\text{n}\cdot\left(\text{V}_1-\text{V}_\text{i}\right)
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

Now, we can solve for \$\text{I}_2\$:

$$\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{I}_\text{k}\left(\text{R}_1\left(1+\text{n}\right)+\text{R}_2\right)+\text{V}_\text{i}}{\text{R}_1\left(1+\text{n}\right)+\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3}\tag4$$

Using your values (without knowing the values of \$\text{R}_3\$), we find:

$$\text{I}_2=\frac{1024}{5\left(61000+\text{R}_3\right)}\tag5$$

---

**Edit**. Because this question is about maximum power transfer we can find the value of \$\text{R}_3\$. In order to do that we need to solve:

$$\frac{\partial\text{P}_{\text{R}_3}}{\partial\text{R}_3}=0\tag6$$

We can use \$(4)\$:

$$\text{P}_{\text{R}_3}=\text{R}_3\text{I}_{\text{R}_3}^2=\text{R}_3\left(\frac{\text{I}_\text{k}\left(\text{R}_1\left(1+\text{n}\right)+\text{R}_2\right)+\text{V}_\text{i}}{\text{R}_1\left(1+\text{n}\right)+\text{R}_2+\text{R}_3}\right)^2\tag7$$

Solving \$(6)\$ using \$(7)\$ we get:

$$\text{R}_3=\text{R}_1\left(1+\text{n}\right)+\text{R}_2\tag8$$

For your circuit we get:

$$\text{R}_3=18\cdot1000\left(1+2\right)+7\cdot1000=61000\space\Omega\tag9$$

And the current and power in \$\text{R}_3\$ will be:

- Current:
  $$\text{I}_{\text{R}_3}=\text{I}_2=\frac{64}{38125}\approx0.00167869\space\text{A}\tag{10}$$
- Power:
  $$\text{P}_{\text{R}_3}=\text{V}_{\text{R}_3}\text{I}_{\text{R}_3}=\text{V}_3\text{I}_2=\frac{32768}{190625}\approx0.171898\space\text{W}\tag{11}$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, teacher is not providing R3, and insisting I don't need it to find I2. So there must be a way of getting rid of R3 somehow?

Comment: @BerkayGünaydın See the edit to my answer.